# Flashing BIOS using an external SPI programmer

Tags: motherboard, bios, flash, post, cmos

Has anyone succeeded with BIOS flashing using an external SPI programmer ? I saw some cheap serial flash spi programmers on eBay for very cheap price such as $3. (CH341A based programmers)

I was wondering if I can use one of those programmers and flash my MX25L8005 BIOS chip with an Award BIOS bin file ? 
Someone told me that Award's .bin file format is a proprietary format and it might not be readable by the SPI programmer. That's why I'm hesitating. Has anyone done this?